# Vector arrays, calculation dot product

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, structure

I am trying write C++ programs that compute the dot product of two given vectors. In vectors a and b only nonzero elements will be stored into array of structures. Each time I am getting irrelevant results. The corrrect result is 50. I think i am not able to read the vectors properly into array of structures. Please advice. Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int n=10; /* vector size limit */
struct element {
int x; /* original index of non-zero array element */
int val ; /* integer non-zero value at index x */
};
element row[n];
element col[n];

int i;
vector<int> a={0,0,7,0,5,0,0,8,0,4,-1};
vector<int> b={0,0,0,5,6,0,0,0,0,5,-1};

void generate_row_and_col()
 {
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=!0)
        {
            row[i].x=i;
            row[i].val=a[i];
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(b[i]!=0)
        {
           col[i].x=i;
           col[i].val=b[i];
        }
    }
}
int dotproduct()
{
/* calculate the dot product of row and col output the result*/
int i=0;
int j=0;
int product=0;
while(row[i].x!=-1 && col[j].x!=-1)
{
    if(row[i].x == col[j].x)
    {
        product=product+row[i].val*col[j].val;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if(row[i].x<col[j].x)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        j++;
    }
}
return product;
}
int main()
{
generate_row_and_col() ;
int r;
r=dotproduct();
cout<<"result="<<r<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You result should be 51 not 50

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=n; i++)` in C++ array indexes go from 0...n-1, where n = array length.

Comment: 5*6+4*5+-1*-1 = 51

Comment: demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e39d16816d6b7410

Comment: I can see a bug if(a[i]=!0)  what is that

Comment: I put -1 s into the array as indicator, when iteration comes -1 they should stop. How can i fix my own loops to have a correct result?

Comment: The array should only store non zero elemenets

Comment: Testing to see if a value is non-zero should be `b[i] != 0` and not `b[i] =! 0`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has `std::inner_product` for *exactly* this purpose. Using it reduces your code to something like this:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = { 0,0,7,0,5,0,0,8,0,4 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 0,0,0,5,6,0,0,0,0,5 };

    std::cout << std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `= !0` is a bug. That was supposed to be `!= 0`.

I'm still guessing at the goal, but perhaps another cleaned version helps:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c53b341fcc24e5e3)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

using Ints = vector<int>;
using Vec = map<int, int>;
Vec row, col;

Vec to_sparse_vec(Ints const& a) {
    Vec v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        if (a[i] != 0) v[i] = a[i];
    }
    return v;
}

int dotproduct(Vec row, Vec col) {
    size_t n = max(row.rbegin()->first, col.rbegin()->first);

    int product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (row[i] && col[i])
            product += row[i] * col[i];
    }
    return product;
}

int main() {
    auto row = to_sparse_vec({ 0, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4 });
    auto col = to_sparse_vec({ 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 });
    cout << "result=" << dotproduct(row, col) << endl;
}
```

This assumes the `Vec` representation is intended as a "sparse vector".

Result is `50` (dropped the `-1` elements)

Comment: Perfect answer ..if OP still is found of flag -1 can use http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2586943d91c247af and answer 50

Comment: Simplified the example code to be more readable, dropping the -1 elements /cc @HariomSingh

Comment: Use of map<int, int>; is exactly how structure was used

Comment: @HariomSingh I took some shortcuts for legibility, of course. You might prefer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1849ef636aa53a93 which treats the sparse vectors as `const` - as well as wasting no space because of the node-based container `std::map`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class T>
T dot_product(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                InputIt2 first2, T value)
{
    while ((first1 != last1)&&(*first1!=-1) && (*first2 !=-1)) {
         value = value + *first1 * *first2;
         ++first1;
         ++first2;
    }
    return value;
}

const int n=10; /* vector size limit */
struct element {
    int x; /* original index of non-zero array element */
    int val ; /* integer non-zero value at index x */
};
element row[n];
element col[n];

int i;
vector<int> a={0,0,7,0,5,0,0,8,0,4,-1};
vector<int> b={0,0,0,5,6,0,0,0,0,5,-1};

int main()
{
    int r;
    r=dot_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0);
    cout<<"result="<<r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

50

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=056e9928988d764f)

Comment: That's incorrect result. Further simplified: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc586f3a890ceab0 correctly prints 51

Comment: @sehe perfect just one addition .He wants only positive values so condition flag can be added for negative

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but anyways. I hope OP achieves his goal

Comment: @sehe I have seen for the first time library valarray ..what is that?

Comment: Using "normal" standard library features only: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec94d08e4f49df7d

Comment: @sehe Inner product would be the best thing to do .But I don't know why OP wants to have negative -1 at the end of vectors(to signify end) .as result using the inner product output is 51 which is correct .But as per OP modification he wants 50 .As he doesn't want to include -1*-1

Comment: Thank you for those solutions, but I am trying to understand what am I doing wrong on my original code?

Comment: I personally have no clue, because I don't know what you intended to do. All the mess with `generate_row_and_col`, the separate `i++` and `j++` - it's all magic to me. Rule number one: _code is for humans_. Expression of intent goes before anything else.

Comment: I am trying to read non zero vector members into array structures, then calculate the dot product. The original vectors don't include -1. generate_row_and_col reads the non zero vector members into array. the dotproduct functions do the calculation

Comment: Why is there `-1`, if "it doesn't include it"? Skipping zeros makes no sense, since the product will be 0 anyways

Comment: @sehe what I could understand is that he wants to create  matrix out of vector then use the matrix .Just want to have  proof of concept that his matrix doesn't take negatives for consideration .his flow is actually in how the matrix is being generated

Comment: I've reached a different analysis, which I paraphrase in my current answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes on the code, it works fine now. But, during initialization row and col arrays on generate_row_and_col function , I only initialize indexes with non zero elements, rest of them are not initialized. This is not causing any error in this program, but in terms of good programming practice,those indexes with 0 values are not initiated and the arrays will look like(garbage, garbage,7, garbage, 5, garbage, garbage....). Can we just limit the generate_row_and_col function, so We can only store non zero value indexes.
Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int n=11; /* vector size */

struct element {
int index; /* original index of non-zero array element */
int value ; /* integer non-zero value at index x */
};
element row[n];
element col[n];

vector<int> a={0,0,7,0,5,0,0,8,0,4,-1};
vector<int> b={0,0,0,5,6,0,0,0,0,5,-1};

void generate_row_and_col()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=0)
        {
            row[i].index=i;
            row[i].value=a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(b[j]!=0)
        {
           col[j].index=j;
           col[j].value=b[j];
        }
    }
}
int dotproduct()
{
/* calculate the dot product of row and col output the result*/
int i=0;
int j=0;
int product=0;
while(row[i].value!=-1 && col[j].value!=-1)
{
    if(row[i].index == col[j].index)
    {
        product=product+row[i].value*col[j].value;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if(row[i].index<col[j].index)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        j++;
    }
}
return product;
}

int main()
{
    generate_row_and_col() ;
    int r;
    r=dotproduct();
    cout<<"Dot Product = "<<r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```